# Subfolders with python code pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-module

Assume that this is my file structure:

```
main.py
modules
  |--> feature1.py
  |--> feature2.py
  |--> feature3.py
```

My `main.py` code is as following:

```
from modules.feature1 import Awesomefeature
...
```

I used the following spec-file for [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/):

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True , icon='icon.ico')
```

Unfortunately I get the following message after I compile my code to a windows executable and execute this (main.exe file):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'modules'
```

Is it completely impossible to have subfolders with pythoncode in it while using pyinstaller?

Comment: Your spec file looks odd.  Did you create it with pyinstaller?

Comment: Yes, but I omitted some tags during my "brute-force" attempt to try every option possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the pathex list to the spec file with a path to the root project directory.

```
a = Analysis(['main.py']),
             pathex=['C:/Users/<user>/Path to the root directory'],
             # rest of spec file
```

Sometimes you need to add module locations to the pathex list.  This is a list of paths that pyinstaller will search first.

Comment: I tried it but I get the same message. The filesize of the executable however, is increased in size.I used: `pathex=['/src/', '/src/modules/'],`

Comment: Remove the leading and trailing '/' from the paths.